# MySQL select where joined table contains all values from predefined list

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join

Say you have three tables: `Film`, `Role` and `Actor`.

What's the best way to query the `Film` table to return the films featuring someone's favorite actors (starting from an array of actor IDs)? **The film needs to feature all the actors from the list** (not just one of them)

Right now, my best guess is to build the query dynamically like so:

```
var favoriteActorIds = [1,2,3];

var query = "SELECT * FROM Film ";

foreach(var id in favoriteActorIds)        
    query += "WHERE EXISTS ( // replacing the WHERE for AND after the first id
        SELECT 1 FROM Role
        WHERE Role.Id = Film.Id
        AND Role.ActorId = " + id;
```

I'm sure I can get such an algorithm to work, but doing a new select or join for each actor just doesn't seem right.

Comment: What's your backend language?PHP or other

Comment: JavaScript... but the code example is pseudo code. The backend language doesn't really matter here.